# My RTL viewer replaces NAND gates with AND gates with the inversion bubbles

Tags: quartus, rtl

I want it to show this MUX only with 3 NAND gates and an Inverter.
so, I specified NAND gate in the verilog HDL code, but it keeps replacing it with AND gates with inversion bubbles without having a single NAND gate. I want to fix this problem. I have to get NAND gates out of it. please let me know if you have any idea.

[image]

Comment: 1. It would probably help to know what program you are using. 2. If your target is an FPGA, it all gets turned into LUTs in the end, so who cares whether it gets drawn as ANDs or NANDs here?

Comment: Same thing happens in verdi which I'm using to check the schematic. I don't know what tool you're using, but I think either you find a switch (if there is) in your setting dialog, or create a named net for each intermediate expression. Since HDL just describes the truth table of combinational logic, the implementation tool will optimize it as long as the truth table still holds. It really doesn't matter how it is shown.

Comment: Learn to love the bubbles. They are all AND gates. The bubbles make explicit which polarity of inputs, when AND'ed together, form the output, which then may or may not have a bubble. It looks screwy at first but once you get used to it you won't want to go back.

Comment: `w0` and `w1` are both NAND gates ... the output inversion is stuck to `y` inputs ... `y` is a NAND gate, the output inversion is at `y~not`

Comment: I downloaded QuartusLiteSetup-15.1.0.185-windows, ModelSimSetup-15.1.0.185-windows and cyclonev-15.1.0.185.qdz. And this is when verilog HDL code runs on them.

Comment: The graphic schematic is just a pretty presentation to make it clear to the human what is going on logically. It is no indication of the underlying implementation which is almost assuredly being implemented in a look up table.

Comment: Muxes are very efficient - this is only 6 transistors using 2 transmission gates and an inverter.

Answer (score 1):

While you can build everything from NAND Gates - these are the most universal - and I guess that is why you want to see em, NAND Gates are not the lowest reduction level of a boolean equation. And this is what your tool will do - it reduces the boolean equation to a optimal point prior to synthesis.

The Goal is to replace the found solution with FPGA LUTS and glue logic or optimized gates of a library of a factory like TSMC... the least thing you want to have is all NAND gates here

Comment: ‘NAND gates are the most universal’ - no, NOR gates are equally universal.

Comment: true. but I remember to have learned that NANDs are more common. But yes NOR is equivalent good

Comment: @hacktastical  In most cmos process, nand gate uses NMOS in series and PMOS in parallel, making the gate more balanced since NMOS performs better than PMOS. A nor gate is the opposite. So nand is better in most case.

Comment: In contemporary processes the p- vs. n- difference is minimal. At any rate the gate types have their delays normalized in the standard cell library, which is what the vast majority of chip designers use.